# Proper way to use Dropwizard dbi onDemand

Tags: postgresql, docker, dropwizard, jdbi

According to the Dropwizard documebtation, DBI dao instances created with DBI.onDemand can open & close connections as needed. I have observed a situation where if you're running Dropwizard inside a Docker & let it idle for a day or so, my daos are not able to reconnect to the rdbms.

What I'm doing is getting the DAO instances once with onDemand at startup & then persisting for the lifetime of the app. Is this the proper way to use onDemand, or should I get a new DAO instance every time I want to run a query?

Answer (score 0):

I have only used dropwizard together with MariaDB, but I would assume that the behavior for postgresql is similar.
I create a single dbi instance at startup and use it to create a single instance for every JDBI interface. These JDBI instances are shared across all resources.

A bare bone example together with Guice would look like this:

Assume you have a JDBI interface UserQuery:

```
@RegisterMapper(UserMapper.class)
public interface UserQuery {

    @GetGeneratedKeys
    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO userData (email, role) values (:email, role)")
    long insertUser(@BindBean User user);

    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM userData WHERE id = :id")
    User getUserById(@Bind("id") long id);
```

Assume you also have another JDBI interface CommentQuery.

At startup, create a dbi onDemand instance for both UserQuery and CommentQuery. Create an injector object and bind the two instances to their classes UserQuery.class and CommentQuery.class. Create a single instance UserResource from the injector object and register it with jersey.
Thus, you would end up with a single UserQuery instance, a single CommentQuery instance and a single UserResource instance.

```
@Override
public void run(MyConfiguration conf, Environment env)  {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(Stage.DEVELOPMENT, new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
            DBI dbi = factory.build(env, conf.getDatabase(), "mydb");
            UserQuery userQuery = dbi.onDemand(UserQuery.class);
            bind(UserQuery.class).toInstance(userQuery);
            CommentQuery commentQuery = dbi.onDemand(CommentQuery.class);
            bind(CommentQuery.class).toInstance(commentQuery);
        }
    });
    UserResource userResource = injector.getInstance(UserResource.class);
    env.jersey().register(userResource);
}
```

The UserResource might look something like this:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource {
    private final UserQuery userQuery;
    private final CommentQuery commentQuery;

    @Inject
    public UserResource(UserQuery userQuery, CommentQuery commentQuery) {
        this.userQuery = userQuery;
        this.commentQuery = commentQuery;
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createUser(User user) {
        long userId = userQuery.insertUser(user);
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setCreatorId(userId);
        comment.setTitle("Hello everyone!");
        commentQuery.insert(comment);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer not do use guice (remove the @Inject annotation in UserResource)

```
@Override
public void run(MyConfiguration conf, Environment env) {
    DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    DBI dbi = factory.build(env, conf.getDatabase(), "mydb");
    UserQuery userQuery = dbi.onDemand(UserQuery.class);
    CommentQuery commentQuery = dbi.onDemand(CommentQuery.class);
    UserResource userResource = new UserResource(userQuery, commentQuery);
    env.jersey().register(userResource);
}
```

This looks very similar to what you have described. I'm also using docker together with dropwizard, but I have not run into the described problem so far.